# Map properties from another Flux | Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, flux

I have two classes as below. We are using reactive programming in Java for development. Initially the address field in Student class will be null as Student table does not have it. Now I have to update the address field in Student class based on the addressId.

How can I do this?

I can do it by converting address Flux to a HashMap and then get values based on address id. But if I do that, am I leaving the reactive programming style? Is there any other way I can do this mapping?

```
public class Student {
  private int id;
  private int addressId;
  private String name;
  private String address;
}

public class Address {
  private int id;
  private String address;
}

public class MapperClass {
  public void map(Flux<Student> students, Flux<Address> addresses ){
    //For each student, I want to take address from addresses map and update the Student class's address field. 
    // I can do something like below:
    addresses.collectMap(a -> a.getId(), a-> a.getAddress()).block();
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you do with that fluxes further? If you pass them further then your desire is unimplementable: if a Student has already been received by flux consumer how could you update it with upcoming Address?

Comment: I have to pass the Flux<Student> as response of my API. I want to pass Flux<Student> with address updated.

Comment: Do you pass addresses Flux, or it exists only for updating students in that mapper?

Comment: No, I'm not passing the addresses Flux as part of response. It's just for processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution uses blocking method, so it's not reactive.
You could construct desired Flux in a reactive way like that:

```
    Flux<Student> updatedStudents = addresses
            .collectMap(Address::getId, Address::getAddress)
            .flatMapMany(addressesMap ->
                    students.doOnNext(student -> student.address = addressesMap.get(student.addressId))
            );
```

How does it work: first, via `collectMap` you get `Mono<Map<Integer, Address>>`, when it's collected, `students` flux would be executed making use of that map.
It is required that 1) `Flux<Address>` is not consumed anywhere else 2) `Flux<Address>` is finite. Otherwise desired behaviour is not possible.